# Angular2 DatePipe is not working in ios

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript

I have tried to add a `DatePipe` on my `Nativescript` + `Angular 2` mobile application. It is working on the Android emulator but getting error on the ios emulator.

> Error: file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9427:77: JS ERROR Error: Error in pages/home/home.component.html:86:29 caused by: Invalid argument '2016-11-15T10:51:07+0300' for pipe 'DatePipe'

My Code :`<Label col="1" [text]="item.datetime | date:'yMMMd'"></Label>`

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

As per [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html) `DatePipe` can be used like `date_expression | date[:format]` where `expression` is a date object or a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch) or an ISO string so make sure that your `item.datetime` value will be date object or number in milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks @ranakrunal9 , I have added Momentjs, Now Its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Label class="EventTime" col="0" row="0" [text]="item.StartDate | date:'jm'"></Label>
```

As per doc

1. 'medium': equivalent to 'yMMMdjms' (e.g. Sep 3, 2010, 12:05:08 PM
   for en-US)
2. 'short': equivalent to 'yMdjm' (e.g. 9/3/2010, 12:05 PM for en-US)
3. 'fullDate': equivalent to 'yMMMMEEEEd' (e.g. Friday, September 3,
   2010 for en-US)
4. 'longDate': equivalent to 'yMMMMd' (e.g. September 3, 2010 for
   en-US)
5. 'mediumDate': equivalent to 'yMMMd' (e.g. Sep 3, 2010 for en-US)
6. 'shortDate': equivalent to 'yMd' (e.g. 9/3/2010 for en-US)
7. 'mediumTime': equivalent to 'jms' (e.g. 12:05:08 PM for en-US)
8. 'shortTime': equivalent to 'jm' (e.g. 12:05 PM for en-US)